# Text overflows table cell width

Tags: tables

I am building a LaTeX table for a report. I defined a fix width to the second (and last) column, so that it doesn't exceed the size of the page. For some reason, the text is overflowing the size of the cell. Here is my code:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| l | p{12cm} |}
\hline
\textbf{Código} & \textbf{CU03} \\ \hline \hline
\textbf{Nome} & Pesquisa \\ \hline
\textbf{Custo} & 3 \\ \hline
\textbf{Prioridade} & Alta \\ \hline
\textbf{Descrição} & O utilizador faz uma pesquisa simples por um paciente \\ \hline
\textbf{Pré-Condições} & O utilizador está autenticado na aplicação \\ \hline
\textbf{Pós-Condições} & São apresentados os resultados para a pesquisa feita \\ \hline
\textbf{Fluxo de acções} & 
    \begin{tabular} {l  l}
        1.  É pressionado o menu “Documentos” \\
        2.  É preenchido um ou vários dos campos disponíveis (campo1, campo2, campo3 ou       campo3) \\
        3.  É pressionado o botão “Procurar” \\
        4.  São apresentados os resultados \\
    \end{tabular} 
\\ \hline
\textbf{Dependências} & ~\ref{tab: CU01} (CU01)\\ \hline
\textbf{Mokup} & Mokup03 \\ \hline
\textbf{Testes} & TODO \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{CU03}
\label{tab: CU03}
\end{table}
```

and my output is this: 
[image: table with overflowing cell]

One last thing, I am using scribtex to compile my code.

Comment: You should use an `enumerate` environment instead of the inner `tabular`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use an `enumerate` environment, as @egreg suggests, you should replace the inner `tabular`, viz.,

```
  \begin{tabular} {l  l}
```

with something such as

```
\begin{tabular} {p{0.75cm} p{11cm}}
```

and insert `&` between the items' numbers and contents.

Comment: As I said in the other comment, changing to enumerate solved my problem! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Very latte answer ... for exercise and fun (maybe it will helpful to someone):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}% <-- added
\usepackage{enumitem}% <-- added
\usepackage{ragged2e}% <-- added

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\bfseries}l >{\RaggedRight}X @{} }
    \toprule
\textbf{Código} &   \textbf{CU03}           \\ 
    \midrule
Nome            &   Pesquisa                \\ 
Custo           &   3                       \\ 
Prioridade      &   Alta                    \\ 
Descrição       &   O utilizador faz uma pesquisa simples por um paciente 
                                            \\
Pré-Condições   &   O utilizador está autenticado na aplicação 
                                            \\
Pós-Condições   &   São apresentados os resultados para a pesquisa feita
                                            \\
Fluxo de acções &
    \begin{enumerate}[nosep,
                      leftmargin = *,
                      before     = \vspace{-0.8\baselineskip},
                      after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                      ]
    \item   É pressionado o menu “Documentos” 
    \item   É preenchido um ou vários dos campos disponíveis (campo1, campo2, campo3 ou       campo3) 
    \item   É pressionado o botão “Procurar” 
    \item   São apresentados os resultados  
    \end{enumerate}                         \\
Dependências    & ~\ref{tab: CU01} (CU01)   \\  
Mokup           & Mokup03                   \\
Testes          & TODO                      \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]